# How well does a HP Pavilion dm1-4013nr work?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, laptop, hardware, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dm1-4013nr. Has anyone installed Ubuntu on this computer? What sort of problems can I expect?  I would like to set it up as a dual boot with Windows 7.

Comment: If you're curious about hardware compatibility, your best bet is to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and check yourself. If you experience any problems with particular bits of hardware, finding help for particular problems would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Ubuntu Oneiric on the dm1-4142nr.

Everything worked out of the box except for the WiFi. I needed to compile the Broadcom driver manually to get the WiFi working at the correct speed.

Ubuntu 12.04 should fix the WiFi problem as it has the newer Linux kernel 3.2.